# Cast NSValue to CMTimeRange type swift 5.3

Tags: swift5, nsvalue

Swift 5.0 normally cast NSValue to CMTimeRange type, it does not supported in swift 5.3?
For example this worked correctly in Xcode 11.7 (Swift 5.0)

```
let nsValue = NSValue(timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: 12, preferredTimescale: 1), duration: CMTime(seconds: 22, preferredTimescale: 1)))
let value = nsValue as? CMTimeRange
```

But fails in Xcode 12 (Swift 5&) and show warning:

```
Cast from 'NSValue' to unrelated type 'CMTimeRange' always fails
```

Answer (score 1):

[NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue) has [timeRangeValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1385930-timerangevalue) which returns CMTimeRange without explicit cast.

Comment: Yes, but it may return empty struct. Common types can be cast to it's real type without access to property. My question is why it missed for this property?

Answer (score 0):

dharmon is correct:

iOS13: let value = nsValue as? CMTimeRange

iOS14: let value = nsValue.timeRangeValue